# How to colorize jsdoc in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When I open js file, only @param has color. How do you add color to others syntaxs like {object}?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Execute this command from command palette to find TM scope selector needed:

`Developer: Inspect TM Scopes`

Put the selector into
[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Example:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "comment.block.documentation.js entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#6f42c1"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "comment.block.documentation.js storage.type.class.jsdoc",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#d73a49"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "comment.block.documentation.js variable.other.jsdoc",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#24292e"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do I need to put in entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc in this case?
https://i.imgur.com/32E19W2.png

Comment: I want to colorize like github. Example: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/dev/src/core/display/TransformBase.js